# Obtener los valores de los CheckBox seleccionados de un DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

estoy tratando de obtener los valores de todos los checkBox que estan seleccionados dentro de un DataTable. Para esto intente usar este codigo.

```
        let valoresCheck = [];
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
         valoresCheck.push(this.value);
        });
```

Pero solo me obtiene los valores de la pagina actual del DataTable

esta es la forma en la que cargo la tabla

```
function cargarTablaAccess() {
        $("#tableAccess").DataTable({
            "processing": false,
            "lengthMenu": [7, 25, 50, 75, 100],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Zona/ListAccessPoint",
            "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json"
                },
        "pageLength": 7,
        "responsivePriority": 1,
        "columns": [
        {"data": null, "sortable": false, "autoWidth": true, "render": function (data, type, full) {
                        return `<input type="checkbox" value="` + data.id + `" onchange='cambio(` + data.id + `)'>`;}
        },
        {"data": "nombre", "name": "Nombre", "autoWidth": true },
        ],
        "responsive": true
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estuve investigando un poco y encontré esto, igualmente creo que no se termina de adaptar a tu código pero podrías basarte en este

```javascript
let valoresCheck = [];
$("#tableAccess").DataTable().rows().every(function () {
    var data = this.data();
    if (data[0] == true) { // data[0] corresponde a la columna del checkbox
        valoresCheck.push(data[1]); // data[1] correspondería a la columna 'id'
    }
});
```

Este código recorrerá todas las filas del DataTable, sin importar en qué página estén actualmente. `this.data()` es un método proporcionado por la API de DataTable que devuelve los datos de la fila actual. Como estás colocando el checkbox en la primera columna y el 'id' en la segunda, `data[0]` y `data[1]` deberían corresponder a estos valores, respectivamente.

Comment: Te sugerimos revisar [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Bueno luego de bregar con esto todo el día, encontré un forma de hacerlo, no es la mejor ni la mas optima pero por el momento funciona para mi.

```
        let valoresCheck = [];
        var table = $("#tableAccess").DataTable();
        var data = table.rows().nodes();
        data.each(function (value, index) {
            var valor = value.cells[0].children[0].value;
            var check = value.cells[0].children[0].checked;
            if (check)
            {
                valoresCheck.push(valor);
            }            
        });
```

Recorro el datatable obtengo obtengo el valor del checkbox y su estado checked, si check es verdadero significa que esta chequeado por ende inserto el valor en mi array

Answer (score 0):

**Lo hice de esta forma:**

```
//Recorro los datos con checks marcados en el DataTable
        var table = $("#tbUsuariosPerfil").DataTable();

        var valor = "";
        var arregloUsuarios = [];
        var celdaIndex = 0;
        var objeto = "";
        table.$('input[name="chkMarcado"]:checked').each(function () {
            $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function () {
                objeto = $(this);
                valor = $(this).text();
                celdaIndex = objeto[0]._DT_CellIndex.column;

                if (celdaIndex == 0) {
                    arregloUsuarios.push(valor);
                }
            });
        });
        //Fin recorrido
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).